# Why am i having a #value in my index excel formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to create a formula With Index excel but there ia something wrong and i can't figure it out , below is my formula

```
=INDEX(TABLES!$D$98:$S$189,MATCH(1,($C$3=TABLES!$D$97:$S$97)*($C$4=TABLES!$C$98:$C$189)*($C$5=TABLES!$B$98:$B$189)*($C$6=TABLES!$A$98:$A$189),0))
```

when evaluating my formula the problem is with the cells `C3`, `C4`, `C5` & `C6`.

these cells are for data validation tables
tables are for years from 2008 till 2023
and values from $10,000 till $100,000
and categories live private , bus, motor...
and plan like product a, product b...

so what might be the problem??

Comment: sorry the correct formula i used is  =INDEX(TABLES!$D$98:$S$189, MATCH(1, ($C$3=TABLES!$D$97:$S$97) * ($C$4=TABLES!$C$98:$C$189) * ($C$5=TABLES!$B$98:$B$189) * ($C$6=TABLES!$A$98:$A$189), 0)) and it 's not working

Comment: No problem Vera... now you know (we all learn at some time), and thank you for editing. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your MATCH is using a 2D array, it needs to be a 1D array.  Split the horizontal and vertical into two separate MATCH and put them in the correct criterion in the INDEX:

```
=INDEX(TABLES!$D$98:$S$189,MATCH(1,($C$4=TABLES!$C$98:$C$189)*($C$5=TABLES!$B$98:$B$189)*($C$6=TABLES!$A$98:$A$189),0),MATCH($C$3,TABLES!$D$97:$S$97,0))
```

INDEX uses: `INDEX(array,RelativeRow,RelativeColumn)`

By pulling the column Check into it's own MATCH it will return the correct relative column.  We keep the array version of MATCH for the Row checks, but since there is only one column match we can use a standard MATCH.

Note: For older versions of Excel without Dynamic Array, this will require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.